# how to write type in typescript correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I can not understand how to solve a problem.
I have a default state, where **randomActivity** is underlined by red and console shows a mistake.

```
const defaultState: MainState = {
   randomActivity: [],
};
```

The mistake:

```
 Type 'never[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Activity': type, key, participantsts(2739)
mainTypes.tsx(13, 3): The expected type comes from property 'randomActivity' which is declared here on type 'MainState'
(property) MainState.randomActivity: Activity
```

its interface

```
export interface Activity {
  activity: string;
  type: string;
  key: number;
  participants: number;
}

export interface MainState {
  randomActivity: Activity;
}
```

interface of action

```
interface GetActivity {
  type: ActionTypes.GET_ACTIVITY;
  payload: Activity;
}
```

In the randomActivity is emty. Data from api-request is written into it after clicking on the button.
The I get data, write it to the object **randomActivity** and use in the modal window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since randomActivity is of type Activity, set its default to null

```
const defaultState: MainState = {
   randomActivity: null,
};
```

Or ignore setting a default state.

You may also want to set randomActivity as optional.

```
export interface MainState {
  randomActivity?: Activity | null;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it couldn't help. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Activity | undefined'

Comment: I just updated MainState definition to match the answer.